# VueJS get value from an axios promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code

#### Template :

```
<a href="#" class="video" @click.prevent="checkVideo(subItem.id)" :id="subItem.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#playerModal">{{subItem.name}}<span>{{getDuration(subItem.id)}}</span></a>
```

#### VueJS Function :

```
async getDuration(id) {
    var duration  = '';
    await axios.post('/api/v1/checkvideo', {
    menu: id
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data[0].datas.duration)
    return response.data[0].datas.duration;
    });

    //console.log(duration);
    //return duration;
},
```

The problem is that the `console.log` show the values as expected but on the Vue Rendering I get this `[object Promise]` I want to know how to show the values after the promise has been resolved.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 6):

Your code is return axios which is a promise object. If you want to return final duration. You should await axios promise and return the response.

```
async getDuration(id) {
  var duration  = '';
  const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/checkvideo', {
    menu: id
  })
  return response.data[0].datas.duration;
}
```

### EDITED

Since `async` return a promise, [object Promise] will always be rendered on the screen. If you want to get duration on a specific id, I think this is correct to do.

```
data() {
  return {
    id: null, // Maybe you should store the value of `id` here
    duration: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.getDuration(this.id)
},
methods: {
  async getDuration(id) {
    var duration  = '';
    const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/checkvideo', {
      menu: id
    })
    this.duration = response.data[0].datas.duration;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result